# Emoji symbols/emoticons in Python IDLE

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-idle, emoji

I can't encode and display characters in the range \U0001f600-\U0001f650. They are called emoji or emoticons and they are used in all social media.

Python error message:

```
  File "C:\Python\Python342x64\lib\encodings\cp1251.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\U0001f62d' in position 108: character maps to <undefined>
```

This character must look like - . 
I work in Python 3.4.2 (from Sublime Text 2).

How can I display emoji symbols natively in Python IDLE?

Comment: Tcl (and therefore tkinter and idle) supports only characters in the 16bit rahge (U+0000-U+FFFF), so you can't.

Comment: Incidentally, the character in question is [U+1F62D 'LOUDLY CRYING FACE'](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f62d/index.htm) for those of us whose browsers don't render emoji.

Comment: @mata
How can I solve this problem or at least get rid of the error? I can not even write data to a file, again shows an error message. :(