# Show Emoji Characters in Python Terminal

Tags: python, python-unicode

I want to show some emoji characters normally in the python terminal.

I have tried many different methods from installing the emoji module to configure PYTHONIOENCODING. Yet still not working.

Now I'm consider to translate it from other encoding, here is the table:
Character   
Character name  HOUSE BUILDING
Hex code point  1F3E0
Decimal code point  127968
Hex UTF-8 bytes     F0 9F 8F A0
Octal UTF-8 bytes   360 237 217 240
UTF-8 bytes as Latin-1 characters bytes     ð <9F> <8F> 
Hex UTF-16 Surrogates   D83C DFE0

I have used the encode() decode() and codecs module, yet it still produces the same result.

My source code:

```
x = "my lovely house"
print(x)
```

result:

> �my lovely hous

I expect the result will be exactly the same, which the best situation will be input `my lovely house` will generate an output of `my lovely house`

Comment: If you're trying to display emoji in IDLE; you can't, as it's based on Tkinter, as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26694524/emoji-symbols-emoticons-in-python-idle

Comment: Thank you Jammy. I see, would you know how to write this string in mysql database then?

Comment: Store it in a `utf8mb4` column. You'll need to use the unicode escape seqeuences to represent it in the code