# Control signs appear as smileys in visual studio

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

When I type

```
print( "Hello ,\x00\x01\x02world!" )
```

in IDLE, the special singns are ignored, but when I do this in Visual Studio Code, i get this:

> Hello ,☺☻world!

I was wondering just why this is.

```
for x in range(127):
    print(chr(x), end = ' ')
```

Edit: When I run this code, this displays on the terminal in vscode:

> ☺ ☻ ♥ ♦ ♣ ♠
> ♫ ☼ ► ◄ ↕ ‼ ¶ § ▬ ↨ ↑ ↓ → ∟↔▲▼ 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 : ; < = > ? @ A B C D E F >G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z [ \ ]
> ^ _ ` a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z { | } ~

When i do this in IDLE, this shows up:

> ```
>                 ! " # $ % & ' ( ) * + , - . / 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 : ; >< = > ? @ A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z [ \ ] ^ _ ` a >b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z { | } ~
> ```

Maybe this has to do with the vesrion?
im using python 3.9.1.
Oh and for some reason there are these rectangles in IDLE that get printed before the '!', but they can't be shown in the answer. (these rectangles represent the control codes: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters#Control_codes)

It seems that my VSC prints the first characters from code page 437
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437

Comment: Sorry, but I can not reproduce this in my VSCode, have you edited the `editor.fontFamily` in the settings.json file?

Comment: As far as i know I haven't changed anything in the settings. My font family is consolas courier new. Look at the edit i made in the original question.

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate of [Emoji symbols/emoticons in Python IDLE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26694524/emoji-symbols-emoticons-in-python-idle):

As per @mata:

> Tcl (and therefore tkinter and idle) supports only characters in the 16bit rahge (U+0000-U+FFFF), so you can't. –

Comment: I don't think this answers my question. If you google 'Code page 437', you will find out that it is the character set of the original IBM PC. I just wanted to know why the characters \x01 and \x02 get ignored in IDLE when you print them (because they are control codes : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters), but in VSC, when you print these characters, they aren't seen as control codes, but as characters from the 'code page 473' character set and vsc prints smiling faces. If i would print \x03, I would get a heart icon.

Comment: If you feel a question is a duplicate, flag it for closure as such. Answering these questions interferes with site curation. As it is, this question does not appear to be a suitable duplicate target as it's not dealing with emoji or other high-bit characters.

Comment: The question I linked does not have an accepted answer.